# Mysql backtrace insert, where does this data came from?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, backtrace

so i know this is not a typical question and you shouldn't even come to this problem since it's dirty to have more than 1 app use the same db. we have rest apis today, but still there is a lot of old software in rl, thats why i have to deal with this.
i get corrupt data into a mysql table and i don't know where it could come from. all the new apps leave there unique sting in some "source" colmn but the courrupt data of course does not has this integer. i do have the "ime of insert" which i thought should be able to backtrace at least to the server.

is their any log/debug option in mysql which shows me the ips where queries come from (with timestamp)?   my `/var/log/mysql.log` `/var/log/mysql.err` are empty. the **mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41**  runs on **Ubuntu 12.04.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html):

> The server writes information to this log when clients connect or disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients. The general query log can be very useful when you suspect an error in a client and want to know exactly what the client sent to [**mysqld**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld.html).
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> By default, the general query log is disabled. To specify the initial general query log state explicitly, use [`--general_log[={0|1}]`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log). With no argument or an argument of 1, [`--general_log`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log) enables the log. With an argument of 0, this option disables the log. To specify a log file name, use [`--general_log_file=file_name`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file). To specify the log destination, use [`--log-output`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-output) (as described in [Section 5.2.1, “Selecting General Query and Slow Query Log Output Destinations”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/log-destinations.html)).
>
> If you specify no name for the general query log file, the default name is `host_name.log`. The server creates the file in the data directory unless an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory.
>
> To disable or enable the general query log or change the log file name at runtime, use the global [**`general_log`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log) and [**`general_log_file`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file) system variables. Set [**`general_log`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log) to 0 (or `OFF`) to disable the log or to 1 (or `ON`) to enable it. Set [**`general_log_file`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file) to specify the name of the log file. If a log file already is open, it is closed and the new file is opened.

Comment: thank you very much for your fast answer, i also tried to add a trigger which adds the ip of the client to the table, but this seems to be not possible in mysql. general log file is awesome enough thou :)

Comment: @yellowsir you should find what you are looking for in the `USER()` function in MySQL.  Inside a trigger, that should work, while `CURRENT_USER()` will likely not work.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28643/11651

Comment: @michael-sqlbot it's solved but i also thought of it, but i guess i would have got user@% instead of ip. `the old apps are all using the same user btw`